# how to add " span " <span> </span> to each words in the arraylist?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have one arraylist

```
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
  al.add("tree good has");
  al.add("ok go by");
  al.add("see good");
  al.add("dog");
```

how to add " span "   to each words??? For example:

```
  <li> 
     <span>tree</span>  
     <span>good</span> 
     <span>has</span> 
  </li>
  <li> 
     <span>ok</span>  
     <span>go</span> 
     <span>by</span> 
  </li>
  <li> 
     <span>see</span>  
     <span>good</span> 
  </li>
  <li> 
     <span>dog</span> 
  </li>
```

what i tried was: 
the result of this statement was wrong. because the result is add " span " to each row , not earch word.

```
 <% for (int i=0; i<  al.size();i++){ %>
    <li><span><%=al.get(i) %><br></span></li>  
 <%} %>
```

how to add " span "   to each words???

Comment: It depends on how much span do you want to put for each <li>. I guess in this case you want to put every span in the same line. put your <li> out of for and if you want to make more <li>, use double for.

Comment: DId you know EL ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1 This would be cleaner and the logic of the solutions are the sames

Answer (score 1):

You need further split each line into words. Find below code -

```
<% for (int i=0; i<  al.size();i++){
%>
   <li>
<%
     for(int j=0;j<al.get(i).split(" ").length;j++){
 %>
        <span><%=al.get(j) %><br></span>  
<%   }%>
   </li> 
<%}%>
```

Comment: how to solve this issue :Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Line breakpoint:my.jsp [line: 130]
 - The method split(String) is undefined for the 
  type Object

Comment: expected comment... :) 
array list defined as generic, it should be type specific, `List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split method and can add the inner loop to achieve the desired result. it will look like

```
<% for (int i=0; i<  al.size();i++){ 
String[] splitArray = al.get(i).split();%><li>
<% for (int j=0; j<  splitArray.length;j++){ %>
   <span><%=splitArray[j] %></span>  

    <%} %>
</li>
<%} %>
```

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The method split() is undefined for the 
  type Object ..... for the split, I got the errors

Comment: Its not the specific list maybe. you can change the line as `String[] splitArray = (String) al.get(i).split();`

Comment: I would recommend to make the list type specific.

Comment: `splitArray.size()` is wrong statement, array does not have any method size.

Comment: Thanks @SubhrajyotiMajumder for pointing out. updated the answer. :)

Comment: One more thing - `<li><span><%=splitArray[j] %><br></span></li>` this will put each word in span and within li. something like - `<li> <span>tree</span></li> <li><span>good</span></li>`. That is not expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <% for (int i=0; i<  HighlightTermList.size();i++){ %> 
  <li>  <%String str=HighlightTermList.get(i); %> 
      <% String[] splitArray = str.split(" ");
         for(int j=0;j<splitArray.length;j++){ %>
            <span><%=splitArray[j] %></span>
   <%} %> 
   </li>

 <%} %>
```

I combine two answer together. I worked

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with `JSTL`. `JSTL` is better way to using java operations in jsp page. First off all you need to import required libraries to your jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${al}" var="mWord">
                <li>
                    <c:forEach items="${fn:split(mWord,' ')}" var="word">
                        <span>${word}</span>
                    </c:forEach>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can learn detailed differences and advantages between `JSTL` and `JSP Scriptlet` in this [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30334&seqNum=1).